# How to convert OpenCV camera rotation vector to OpenGL rotation vector?

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl

I have a camera rotation matrix 3x3, then i use `Rodrigues` function to get the rotation vector from rotation matrix, but it gives results like `rotVec = (0.02,0.32.-0.01)`, but OpenGL `glRotate` function needs degrees measurment. I think `rotVec = (0.02,0.32.-0.01)` is normilized and i should multiply each element by 360 to get degrees. But there is also coordinate system differences betwen OpenCV and OpenGL. How can i get rotation vector in degrees in OpenGL coordinate system?

Comment: why not using the matrix directly? Otherwise I wouldn't assume it to be normalized, but in radians. Try value*180/pi

Comment: here's an example on how to use the 3d rotation matrix in opengl: it's the variable rtmx https://rdmilligan.wordpress.com/2015/10/05/camera-pose-using-opencv-and-opengl/

Comment: @Micka looks like it works when i use   `gl.Rotate(180 * (float)rotVec[0, 0], -180 * (float)rotVec[1, 0], -180 * (float)rotVec[2, 0]);`

Comment: There is not even a `glRotate` function taking just 3 arguments. And what you do there is not how rodrigues axis-angle representation works

Comment: @derhass `gl.Rotate` in c# takes 3 argument (Euler angles), but i still can not understand how to use glRotate after `rodrigues` correct.

Comment: well, the `rodrigues` function will return an axis-angle representation where the 3D vector encodes the axis of rotation and the _lenght_ of the vector the angle to rotate to. This could be easily transformed to some input for the standard `glRotate`, which just uses separate values. If your `glRotate` uses euler angless, you need to convert to euler first, and there are 6 different euler angle conventions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV and OpenGL use different 3D coordinate systems, and different in-memory matrix representations.  OpenGL matrices are stored in column-major order in memory. For example:

```
m[0]     m[4]     m[8]     m[12]=tx
m[1]     m[5]     m[9]     m[13]=ty
m[2]     m[6]     m[10]    m[14]=tz
m[3]=0   m[7]=0   m[11]=0  m[15]=1
```

This is transposed compared to normal OpenCV matrices, which are in row-major order. For example:

```
m[0]     m[1]     m[2]     m[3]=tx
m[4]     m[5]     m[6]     m[7]=ty
m[8]     m[9]     m[10]    m[11]=tz
m[12]=0  m[13]=0  m[14]=0  m[15]=1
```

So you need to keep track of whether your matrices are in OpenCV or OpenGL format.  They can be converted by transposition (`cv::Mat::t()` operator).
So, rather than using Rodrigues() (assuming your rotation matrix is a `cv::Matx33`), you can convert it to `cv::Matx44` by padding it with a zero translation, and concatenate directly with the OpenGL MODELVIEW transform using `glMultMatrix(xform.t().val)`.  (`t()` creates the transpose, and `.val` is a pointer to the transposed array of 16 floats.)

If you do that, it probably still won't work, because in the OpenCV 3D coordinate system used for camera calibration, +X is to the right, +Y is down, and +Z is in front of the camera. In the "normal" OpenGL coordinate system, +X is to the right, +Y is up, and +Z is behind the camera (that is, only negative Z coordinates are visible). Both are right-handed systems, related by a 180 degree rotation about X.  So you could insert such a rotation at the bottom of your OpenGL MODELVIEW stack.  Then you could pass OpenCV 3D coordinates directly to OpenGL.

(If you are wanting to use OpenCV camera calibration, eg. for correctly aligned augmented reality, then you also need to set up your projection matrix carefully, using the camera's intrinsics matrix.  But that is a separate question...)

But since your actual question is how to get the rotation vector in degrees in the OpenGL coordinate system, then you need to:

- decide whether the matrix is in OpenGL or OpenCV format; if OpenGL, transpose it.
- call Rodrigues() to get the vector.
- take the vector length, which is the rotation angle in radians, and multiply by 180/pi to get degrees.
- call glRotate(vector.x, vector.y, vector.z, degrees) to perform the rotation.

There should be no need to consider the coordinate system differences, since both systems are right-handed.  The result will be in the coordinate system appropriate for the initial matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helped me with my motion capture system)